# Highlight all date values in word doc using python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm looking for python code to highlight all date values with format `"MM-DD-YYYY"`  in a word document. I'm using word `docx` to do so. below is my code but it is highlighting complete line instead of the only date.

```
for p in doc.paragraphs:  

 date1 = re.findall(r"[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-(?!0000)[0-9]{4}", p.text)
    for run in p.runs:
    if date1:
    run.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW
```

Comment: That `if` line is going to be executed for all runs as soon as the text is found anywhere. It is not good Python code at all.

Answer (score 3):

For your script to only add the color to the date it would have to be alone in the run.

Consider this example:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.enum.text import WD_COLOR_INDEX

document = Document()

document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)

p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
p.add_run('bold').bold = True
p.add_run(' 05-03-2018 ')
p.add_run('italic.').italic = True

document.save('demo.docx')
```

And then:

```
doc = Document('demo.docx')

for p in doc.paragraphs:
    for run in p.runs:
        date1 = re.findall(r"[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-(?!0000)[0-9]{4}", run.text)
        if date1:
            run.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW

doc.save('demo.docx')
```

---

**Update:** Maybe this could help you. It will search for the string in the paragraph text. If found it will save the runs to a list, delete the paragraph text and then rebuild the runs. A run with a match inside is rebuilt with a special syntax to color the date.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.enum.text import WD_COLOR_INDEX

document = Document()

document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)

p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
p.add_run('bold text. ').bold = True
p.add_run('Current date: 05-03-2018 ')
p.add_run('italic.').italic = True

document.save('demo.docx')

doc = Document('demo.docx')

pattern = r"[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-(?!0000)[0-9]{4}"

for p in doc.paragraphs:

    if re.findall(pattern, p.text):
        runs = list(p.runs)
        p.text = ''

        for run in runs:
            match = re.search(pattern, run.text)

            if not match:
                newrun = p.add_run(run.text)
                if run.bold:
                    newrun.bold = True
                if run.italic:
                    newrun.italic = True
            else:
                start, end = match.span()
                p.add_run(run.text[0:start])
                colored = p.add_run(run.text[start:end])
                colored.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW
                p.add_run(run.text[end:len(run.text)+1])

doc.save('demo.docx')
```

Comment: Thank You Anton, however the code is not really highlighting all dates.Below is the content of source file. date 10/11/2001 was not highlighted, I assume it is mainly because the date is split between two p.text values.                                        
Address: 
Social Security Number: 388-45-9719 
e-mail:sravik1990@gmail.com
Date of Birth: 12/11/1992
Credit card:

Be sure to list expenses below along with either the reason or budget category for the expense for tracking purposes. Remember to attach all receipts to this form 10/11/2001.
 
Another Date: 10/11/2010

Comment: @Savita This has to do with the lookup-pattern. `"[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-(?!0000)[0-9]{4}"
` doesnt match your example dates.

Comment: I had changed pattern to " pattern = r"\b[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(?!0000)[0-9]{4}" sorry I missed to mention that. It did highlight few dates but  not all

Comment: @Savita I would probably try to find one of those dates and understand why it is not catching it.